# Calculate a year from a set of dates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am given an array containing periods for a year as following.

```
$year = '2016';
$periods = [
      [
          'name' => "Name One",
          'startDate' => '01/01/2016',
          'endDate' => '03/31/2016'
      ],
        [
            'name' => "Name Two",
            'startDate' => '04/01/2016',
            'endDate' => '12/31/2016'
        ]
    ];
```

The number of periods may vary, hence, the array *periods* may have any number of elements (say 5 elements, meaning 5 periods for the given year). Now I need to make sure that **the periods do really make up a year**, that is, **two periods cannot overlap** and the **periods collectively do sum up to be the specified year**.

I've tried many different ways, but failed to come up with any efficient solution at all.
I am using Laravel 5, hence Carbon package. But I'll be glad to get this done even in Basic PHP. So all suggestions are welcome

Comment: when you say that you need to "make sure" that they form a year, do you mean "check whether they form a year" or "make them form a year if they don't"?

Comment: I think starting with a sort of this array would be helpful, on the start date (ascending). Then you could compare that the next start date > the previous one, and one day greater than the previous end date.

Comment: @hairraisin "check whether they form a year"

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try - there may be a more elegant solution but I think this works. I've used Carbon, as it's a got some very useful helper methods.

I've assumed your `$periods` array will be in date order. If it's not, you could just `usort` it.

```
$year = '2016';
$periods = [
    [
        'name' => "Name One",
        'startDate' => '01/01/2016',
        'endDate' => '03/31/2016'
    ],
    [
        'name' => "Name Two",
        'startDate' => '04/01/2016',
        'endDate' => '12/31/2016'
    ]
];

// set a start position
$currentPosition = Carbon::create($year, 1, 1)->startOfDay();
// and the end of the year
$endOfYear = Carbon::create($year, 1, 1)->addYear()->startOfDay();

// iterate periods
foreach ($periods as $period) {
    $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $period['startDate'])->startOfDay();
    $end = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $period['endDate'])->endOfDay();

    // start of this period should follow the last (??)
    if ($start < $currentPosition) {
        throw new Exception("$start is earlier than $currentPosition");
    }

    // must follow on from the current position
    if ($currentPosition->diffInDays($start) > 0) {
        throw new Exception("$start doesn't follow $currentPosition");
    }

    // check it doesn't go over the end of the year
    if ($currentPosition->addDays($start->diffInDays($end)) > $endOfYear) {
        throw new Exception("$end takes us over the end of the year!");
    }

    $currentPosition = clone $end;
}

// did we reach the end?
if ($currentPosition->addDay()->startOfDay() != $endOfYear) {
    throw new Exception("Full year not accounted for");
}

// we're done
echo 'Full year accounted for'.PHP_EOL;
```